# Minimum virtual memory (swapfile) size setting

Tags: virtual-memory

Is possible set the minimum swapfile size in OS X?

Currently OS X allocating swapfiles on demand, e.g. when when need 3.2GB will allocate 4GB and so on. But when the swap requirements start getting low the system deletes un-needed swap files. All these IO operations are very IO intensive.

Therefore looking for a way how to define the *minimum* swap file size, e.g. I want default allocate minimum 4GB virtual memory. When the system will need more than 4GB will allocate on demand, but at releasing will never release under 4GB size.

Is this possible somewhat? (using lion)

Comment: I don't think you can do that in OSX.  What Version of the OS do you have?

Comment: using lion - if i remember good the latest bigger vm improve was in the snow leopard...

Comment: you're correct, there hasn't been big changes in that area. You can always disable the swap and see how it goes. Some people reports having no problems whatsoever. Granted if swap is needed, the os will likely crash…

Comment: From a different perspective, another question that seeks to avoid intensive operations: [Mac virtual memory: how to make OS X create swap (page) files as freely with a normal boot as it does with a safe boot (swapfile1 etc)](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/88750/8546)

Comment: To complement the comment by @MartínMarconcini: [Why would I disable swap file in Mac OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24502/8546)

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this? (Or did you restrict the software that was causing the swapfiles to grow in the first place?)

Comment: @bmike - still looking. Now rarely swapping now because have 8GB of memory, but simply would be nice to know how to set the MINIMUM swapfile size.

Answer (score 2):

> … set the minimum swapfile size …

[dynamic_pager(8) Mac OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/dynamic_pager.8.html)

With Terminal, a one-off command to convert a property list to a format that will be easily editable:

`sudo plutil -convert xml1 com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist`

Then if you're happy to edit with nano:

`sudo nano /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist`

Use option `-S` to set a size in bytes, then save that property list and either:

- simply, safely, restart the Mac; or
- unload then load the daemon – but that may be risky (and I suspect that only a restart of the Mac will reap the potential benefits).

That's a single size for all files, and any use of option `-S` will cause `dynamic_pager` to **not** use variable sized paging files:

- we can not simply set a minimum – alone – amongst that set of variables.

> … I want default allocate minimum 4GB …

Based on my tests with Mountain Lion, you might find that `dynamic_pager` will quietly fail to begin with a file that is so large.

Proceed with caution – pay attention to the actual size of `swapfile0` and if it is zero bytes, then beware of inexplicable reductions to free space on the volume where the files are expected.

> … at releasing will never release under 4GB size. …

Consider `dynamic_pager` option `-L`

> > If there are more than low-water-trigger bytes free in the external paging files, the kernel will coalese in-use pages and signal dynamic_pager to discard an external paging file. Low-water-trigger must be greater than high-water-trigger + filesize.