# OS X Mountain Lion Terminal and tabs take ages to load

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

When I open a new Terminal tab I have to wait at least 10-20 seconds before I can work with it, I have followed previous suggestions here: [How do I speed up new Terminal tab loading time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41743/how-do-i-speed-up-new-terminal-tab-loading-time)

But so far I still have slow tabs. When I open the inspector during a tab loading I see the following process:

- login
- bash
- bash
- ruby
- sw_vers
- dirname
- sh

The bottom 4 start and stop during the inactive time in my tab, until the tab is finally useable and I only have *login* and *bash* remaining.

Can anyone offer any help here, it's very frustrating.

TIA

Comment: Can you past in your config files (.bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at your .profile file (`vi ~/.profile`) to check if someone (some program) has added something there that takes the time?

Try to create a new user on your Mac (System Preferences -> Users), log in as this user and see if the problem also happens.  If not, compare this user's .profile and the one where the delay happens (or at least the experiment will tell if it is something system specific or user specific).

Also there is the global file /etc/bashrc which is processed for all bash shells for all users.  Something added there could cause a delay for all shells for all users.

Comment: This looks like it was the problem, in the past I hadn't had anything in there, but something I installed through Homebrew recently left me with hundreds of source lines, it turns out the bash_profile file added this line to itself each time a terminal tab was opened!