# How to debug slow terminal prompt?

Tags: terminal, macos, performance

Ever since I upgraded to Mavericks, the Terminal prompt became a bit slower at coming back. It's not a huge deal, but there's now a slight noticeable delay before the prompt comes back (maybe like a quarter of a second)  which gets annoying over time.

How would I debug this issue? Basically, is there a way to see what exactly it's doing in that time? What are common causes of such a slow down?

Comment: Are you using bash, zsh? you can try cleaning out the .asl logs `sudo rm /private/var/log/asl/*.asl`

Comment: @l'L'l: I'm using `bash`. Just did that, but it doesn't seem like it changed the speed much.

Comment: the next thing you could try is `/bin/zsh -i -x` which should tell you what is running prior to the prompt showing. Also, make sure you quit and re-launch terminal after clearing the logs :)

Comment: @l'L'l: yeah I did restart the terminal. Also isn't that for `zsh`? I'm using `bash`

Comment: you're using zsh in that instance as a debugger (of sorts).

Comment: @l'L'l: hmm, just ran it and it showed me that it's just running `/usr/libexec/path_helper` and setting the `PATH`. Is there a way to see what gets run "between" prompts? The problem is not really slow startup, just that it takes a while to come back (i.e. I open Terminal, then hit enter, and it takes a while to show me another line)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11546/discussion-between-lll-and-houbysoft)

Comment: For info on debugging it, see all answers here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41743/how-do-i-speed-up-new-terminal-tab-loading-time

Answer (score 5):

I was encountering a 5-second lag (!) between Terminal window creation and receiving a bash prompt.  (This was on a fresh install of Mavericks on which I had copied user profiles from another machine.)  I removed all the *.asl files in /private/var/log/asl/ as mentioned here, and it completely solved my lag issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Where is here? a link would be helpful

Comment: @Mark - I think He meant **l'L'l** comment.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't "always enough" see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41743/how-do-i-speed-up-new-terminal-tab-loading-time