# Terminal speed up doesn't accept command line arguments from outside source?

Tags: terminal, command-line, performance

From a [previous suggestion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41743/how-do-i-speed-up-new-terminal-tab-loading-time/71930#71930) I changed terminals startup command from default to '/usr/bin/bash' which I created as a link to '/bin/bash' which stops terminal from login in every time I open a tab

This does successfully speed up using terminal and stop it from searching for the login time which is stored in the '.asl' logs.

My problem is it also stops terminal from accepting command line arguments delivered from another program when opening terminal.

Now I could go back to letting terminal login and do the search, especially as I recently upgrade to an SSD and the search is probably a lot faster on it anyway. But I would still like to know why Terminal won't accept outside CML arguments.

I have alfred installed and it has a way of opening terminal by typing ">" followed by a command. With the terminal command set to be /usr/bin/bash it no longer runs the given command though? So I can type '>ls' in Alfred and it opens up the Terminal prompt but no sign of ls. If I switch to '/bin/bash' it works again.

Any way to fix this without allowing terminal to use login?

Comment: I think Alfred uses an AppleScript like `tell application "Terminal"`, `activate`, `do script q`, `end tell`. So I don't know how that would be affecting it. I suppose it's possible that the `do script` action adds something to the `login` command, and that's what the problem is.

Comment: The correct location should be /bin/bash. Using an absolute path, there is not searching for Terminal. The loading should be instantaneous. If you're not experiencing that then you've got a different problem and this is the symptom. Yes, the .bash* files can, in theory, delay access to the prompt if you put time consuming commands in there, but that's after bash has started. It sounds like you may be memory starved or perhaps should run Onyx to clean your system.

Comment: Quick workaround: What's making the login slow is that for some reason it tries to load `/var/log/asl/*.asl`. You can use [this answer's suggestion](http://superuser.com/a/47781) from SuperUser.

Comment: @WaltStoneburner The speed isn't as much of an issue now. As the other link found out, even using terminal with just /bin/bash means that the login message is suppressed, the search in '/var/log/asl/*.asl' still takes place, which is something I wanted to stop. Using '/usr/bin/bash', which is just a link to '/bin/bash' anyhow stops this search from happening at all. My issue is that Alfred no longer can send a command to the terminal and have it run.