# How to prevent OSX from allocating as much virtual memory as there is space available on the hard drive?

Tags: macos, memory

I recently had data loss because the hard drive was completely used up by virtual memory and some programs couldn’t handle zero free space on the hard drive. How can I prevent this from happening (besides always keeping a few GB as a buffer)?

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of [Is there a way to limit the size of the disk swap file in Mac OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/64440/8546) (2012-09-19), which has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can propose you one way to do that, although it is not complete.

You can set memory limit per process using `launchctl limit` (see the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html)). However this is per process not system wide.

In real life, few processes are consuming vast amount of memory. Therefore, I would advise you to look at `Activity Monitor` output and see which are the process consuming the most. Count the ones that are using more than 20% of your RAM. How many such processes do you have? Let's assume *n* and assume that you have *m* GB of RAM. How much maximum swap space do you want to use? Let's assume *s* GB of swap.

I would do the following calculation: `(m + s - 1) / n = <max memory per process in GB>`

Convert the GB into B: `<max memory per process in GB> * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = <max mem per proc in B>`

Now try this limit and see if it works (note, this setting will be lost after a reboot, so it is "safe" to perform):

```
sudo launchctl limit rss <max mem per proc in B> <max mem per proc in B + 1073741824>
```

If you are happy with this choice, then you can save them, so they are permanent. Edit the file `/etc/launchd.conf` and add:

```
limit rss <max mem per proc in B> <max mem per proc in B + 1073741824>
```

Comment: @bmike I am sorry but can't you put your comments in your own answer or comment? I am not sure the ton you use fits with mine. Although valuable, I will ask for you edit to be undone. Feel free to add it as a comment of my answer or as a plain answer.

Comment: Just click edit and revert my changes - do be aware that the site is very open to more than one contributor to any post. What I proposed is an answer component and not a comment IMO, but I'll probably copy your words and add mine if that makes you feel better. I figured you did the bulk of the work and wanted the authorship to remain yours, but I'm open to leaving your entry as is and adding a second answer.

Comment: I know, I also did set some of my post as community wiki. But this time I felt that the style of our answers were too different, and it felt awkward. Thank you, I did found that one can revert changes! Great tool!

Comment: @Huygens a bit confused, shouldn't one multiply when converting from GB to byte?

Comment: @FrancisLaclé indeed! You are right. I will edit the answer and correct that. A 5y+ old bug somewhat ;-)